# Why do I need monitor mode for setting up a WLAN access point?

Tags: networking, wifi

I am reading about setting up the Raspi as a WLAN access point. There is [an article (German)](http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.de/Magazin/2014/01/Pi-Point-Raspberry-Pi-als-WLAN-Zugangspunkt) that says for the output of `iw list`:

> In der umfänglichen Ausgabe müssen im Bereich Supported interface modes die Modi *AP*, *managed* und *monitor* auftauchen.

Translated by me:

> In the verbose output, the section "supported interface modes" must list *AP*, *managed* and *monitor*.

I understand that the monitor mode is even more promiscuous than the promiscuous mode and is used for monitoring and/or sniffing. However, I don't understand why that would be necessary to set up an access point.

My main concern is that the Raspberry 3 built-in Wifi does not support the *monitor* mode, so the article would not apply for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked article uses [Pi-Point](https://www.pi-point.co.uk/documentation/) which says in their documentation:

> Your dongle will also need to support 'AP' mode which you can verify by typing iw list and under the 'Supported interface modes' you will hopefully see 'AP' listed along with others like 'managed' and 'monitor'.

This is different in that it only requires *AP* and neither *managed* nor *monitor*. This makes it suitable for the Raspberry 3 built-in Wifi.